# Wanted to count the number of orders by date with query function in google sheet

Tags: mysql, google-sheets

I am trying to count the total number of orders today with the query function and sort.

I can count it by status through this.

```
=QUERY('2021'!A1:AA5000, "select G,
count(V) where V is not null and V ='In Process'
group by G
order by count(V) desc
label count(V) 'New Order'")
```

but not sure how to count it by date
I have column C with date format yyyy-mm-dd. I wanted to show the total numbers of orders yesterday.
I tried this

```
=QUERY('2021'!A1:AA5000, "select G,
count(C) where C is not null and C =TODAY()-1
group by G
order by count(C) desc
label count(C) 'yesterday Orders'")
```

it throws a #value or #error

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=QUERY('2021'!A1:G, "select G, count(C) where C = date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by G order by count(C) desc label count(C) 'yesterday Orders'", 1)
```

and see if that works?

### REFERENCE

- [Using date criteria in QUERY](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-use-date-criteria-in-query-function-in-google-sheets/)